# how to add pythonpath to my files

Tags: python, python-3.x, sublimetext3

how to set python path for my files !?
i tried to run my code on windows 8 using ctrl+B but it gave the following error.

```
'python' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
[Finished in 0.1s with exit code 1]
[shell_cmd: python -u "C:\Users\vishal_pc\Documents\python_codes\helloworld.py"]
[dir: C:\Users\vishal_pc\Documents\python_codes]
[path: c:\Program Files (x86)\AMD APP\bin\x86_64;c:\Program Files (x86)\AMD APP\bin\x86;c:\Program Files (x86)\Intel\iCLS Client\;c:\Program Files\Intel\iCLS Client\;C:\Windows\system32;C:\Windows;C:\Windows\System32\Wbem;C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;C:\Program Files\Intel\Intel(R) Management Engine Components\DAL;C:\Program Files\Intel\Intel(R) Management Engine Components\IPT;C:\Program Files (x86)\Intel\Intel(R) Management Engine Components\DAL;C:\Program Files (x86)\Intel\Intel(R) Management Engine Components\IPT;c:\Program Files (x86)\ATI Technologies\ATI.ACE\Core-Static;C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Live\Shared;C:\Program Files (x86)\QuickTime\QTSystem\;C:\Program Files\Intel\WiFi\bin\;C:\Program Files\Common Files\Intel\WirelessCommon\;C:\Program Files\Microsoft\Web Platform Installer\]
```

somebody please help!

Comment: i m using sublimetext3 ide.

Comment: Add your Python directory to the PATH environmental variable. Typically, it would be C:\Python27 or something similar.

Comment: i added my python dir to the PATH environmental variables but still my sublimetext3 ide is giving the same error!?

Answer (score 1):

You should check this link [Adding python to the path](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3701646/how-to-add-to-the-pythonpath-in-windows-7). The problem is that your computer cannot find python at this point, you need to "show" him where the python is.
Probably if it will be installed in a directory like C:/Python27 depending on the version of the python you use.